# Designing a table / grid check-box group with bootstrap or pure css

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins

What I'm trying to do is a create a grid (could be a simple  or a bootstrap grid...) where each cell has an image and potentially some text, and touching / clicking anywhere within the cell would make it act as a check-box (i.e. perhaps the border colors or background change to show it's been selected or un-selected).

So the whole table with it's cells is a giant check-box group.

Any elegant approaches with Bootstrap / jQuery / pure CSS would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example I created that each time you click on one of the data cells, an alert pops up with the value inside of the cell. You could manipulate this to save it into a variable or whatever fit your requirements.

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/j5cQx/)

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable">

            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>

            <tr>
                <td>Data 1</td>
                <td>Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 3</td>
                <td>Data 4</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('#myTable td').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("dark-cell");
        alert($(this).html());
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.dark-cell {
    background: #b00;
}
```

Comment: Elegant and simple! This should work for what I need. I'm feeling dumb right now :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of jqGrid, http://www.trirand.com/blog/.  It has built-in functionality to highlight a row when a user clicks/taps any cell in the row.  You can also show/hide the checkbox at the beginning of a row.

Demos
http://www.trirand.net/demo/aspnet/mvc/jqgrid/

Docs
[http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs)

Download
http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6